# Very large dataset with more than 2000 variables descriptive statistics in multicore

Tags: r, descriptive-statistics, parallel-computing

I deal with very large datasets everyday with millions of rows and thousands of columns.

I can sample down to do descriptive statistics, but the people i work with here do not believe in sampling down because resources are not an issue here. Access to 32 cores and over 250 GB memory in unix is available. What i like to do is send 1 variable to one core, 32 variabels to 32 cores at the same time and calculate min,max,mean,std,quantiles etc. I like to do this in R.

Can someone tell me how i can do this in R.

Comment: Did you try $parallel$ package or plyr package, both have facilities for parallel computing

Comment: `foreach`, `doParallel` packages work beautifully just by replacing `for loop` with `foreach` and `%dopar% `